# Updating rows of the same index

Tags: python, pandas

Given a DataFrame `df`:

```
                            yellowCard secondYellow redCard
match_id          player_id                                
1431183600x96x30  76921              X          NaN     NaN
                  76921            NaN            X       X
1431192600x162x32 71174              X          NaN     NaN
```

I would like to update duplicated rows (of the same index) resulting in:

```
                            yellowCard secondYellow redCard
match_id          player_id                                
1431183600x96x30  76921              X            X       X
1431192600x162x32 71174              X          NaN     NaN
```

Does `pandas` provide a library method to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your df is multi-indexed on `match_id` and `player_id` so I would perform a [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) on the `match_id` and fill the `NaN` values twice, ffill and bfill:

```
In [184]:
df.groupby(level=0).fillna(method='ffill').groupby(level=0).fillna(method='bfill')

Out[184]:
                             yellowCard  secondYellow  redCard
match_id          player_id                                   
1431183600x96x30  76921               1             2        2
                  76921               1             2        2
1431192600x162x32 71174               3           NaN      NaN
```

I used the following code to build the above, rather than use `x` values:

```
In [185]:
t="""match_id player_id yellowCard secondYellow redCard
1431183600x96x30  76921              1          NaN     NaN
1431183600x96x30  76921            NaN           2       2
1431192600x162x32 71174              3          NaN     NaN"""
df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\s+', index_col=[0,1])
df

Out[185]:
                             yellowCard  secondYellow  redCard
match_id          player_id                                   
1431183600x96x30  76921               1           NaN      NaN
                  76921             NaN             2        2
1431192600x162x32 71174               3           NaN      NaN
```

**EDIT** there is a [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill) and [`bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.bfill.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.bfill) method for groupby objects so this simplifies to:

```
In [189]:
df.groupby(level=0).ffill().groupby(level=0).bfill()

Out[189]:
                             yellowCard  secondYellow  redCard
match_id          player_id                                   
1431183600x96x30  76921               1             2        2
                  76921               1             2        2
1431192600x162x32 71174               3           NaN      NaN
```

You can then call [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates):

```
In [190]:
df.groupby(level=0).ffill().groupby(level=0).bfill().drop_duplicates()

Out[190]:
                             yellowCard  secondYellow  redCard
match_id          player_id                                   
1431183600x96x30  76921               1             2        2
1431192600x162x32 71174               3           NaN      NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do a

```
df.groupbby([df.match_id, df.player_id]).min()
```

the default behavior for `NaN` will ignore them. For DataFrames of the form in your example (all disagreements are between `NaN`s and filled values), this will do the job.

**Edit**

I assumed the `X` values were placeholders for floats. For strings, use a combination of `ffill` and `bfill` like EdChums answer (which should be accepted).

Comment: It seems to do the job but only in part. It filled `X`'s of the first row (the duplicated) with `inf`s. I think I can `df.replace()` the values but perhaps there is a better way? Edit: Oddly it did not replace the `inf` value at [`1431183600x96x30`  `76921`, `yellowCard`]

Comment: What is ``df.yellowCard.dtype``?

Comment: OK, see update (also, you should accept EdChum's answer, IMHO).